# Solving a quadratic matrix equation with non-squared matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I would to solve $X=T^TT$ ,I assume that the matrices are real, we know $ X $ and we seek

a solution in $ T $.

**Case 1:** $\operatorname{rank}(X)>n $

There are no solutions in $ T $.

**Case 2:** $ \operatorname{rank}(X)\leq n $

There is an orthogonal matrix in $ P$ and a diagonal matrix

$$ D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n,0,\cdots,0) $$ s.t $ X=PDP^T $ and $ \lambda_i\geq 0 $ then $ W^TW=D $ with $ W=TP^{-T} $.

Since $ P$ is known, it suffices to obtain a solution in $W$ we choose $ W=[S_{n,n},0_{n,m-n}] $ with $ S^TS=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n) $
, for instance ,$ S=\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1},\cdots,\sqrt{\lambda_n}) $

I just want someone to confirm me if it's a true.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am confused. Where is the equation? Are you looking for a general nonsquare solution $T$ of the equation $X=T^TT$? Then it is completely specified via SVD for $X$;

Comment: Is this the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828285/solving-a-quadratic-matrix-equation-with-non-squared-matrix (question with same author and same title)?

Comment: I've given an answer to a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367812/solving-a-quadratic-matrix-equation-with-transpose-matrix/4003819#4003819