# Solving a quadratic matrix equation with transpose matrix

Tags: matrix-equations

Let $X$ be an unknown matrix and $A$ a known matrix, and suppose the problem is well posed in terms of dimensions.

Is there any way to solve the matrix equation $X^TX=A$, analytically or using numerical methods?

Comment: Is $A$ real or complex? Do $X$ and $A$ have the same dimensions, i.e. $n\times n$, or do you want a low-rank approximation with a smaller $X$?

Comment: $A$ is real, and they have the same dimensions.

Comment: Have you looked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158219/is-a-matrix-multiplied-with-its-transpose-something-special ? It gives some (fairly obvious) properties of $X^TX$.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll read it carefully

Answer (score 0):

The matrix $A$ is symmetric. Thus there exists a unitary matrix $U$ such that $UAU^T=D=diag(d_{i})$ is diagonal with real non-negative entries (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Complex_symmetric_matrices).

Thus,
$$ A = X^TX = (U^\dagger \sqrt{D})(\sqrt{D}U^*). $$

Inspection tells you that
$$ X = \sqrt{D}U^*. $$

Note that this is not unique. For any orthogonal matrix $R$, $\tilde X=RX$ is also a solution.